# cambiar automáticamente el idioma a una app según la región

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

tengo una gran duda, que es lo que hay que configurar o que clases de métodos llevar a cabo para controlar los idiomas en una app, en este caso la app que estoy creando esta echa en expo-cli, ya esta terminada, pero esa es mi duda, el idioma, en mi aplicación todos los string los escribí en ingles, pero quiero que cambie de idioma según la región y no se como implementar eso, en caso de que si hay que refactorizar el código lo haré

Comment: Tu archivo de strings debe ser **Localizable**, eso permite generar varios archivos con el mismo nombre Ej: `Localizable.strings` pero haciendo referencia al idioma que selecciones.

Comment: Lastima que tu pregunta no este formulada correctamente, amigo, debes partir de un codigo que hayas creado e indicarnos que problemas estas teniendo en el codigo, no puedes solo darnos una descripcion, asi no funciona el sitio, porfavor pasate por el recorrido [tour] y leer [ask], aunque todavia puedes reformular tu pregunta e investigar un poco mas al respecto para darnos una pregunta que sea acta para recibir una respuesta, es interesante saber como se podria hacer esto, puesto que requiero algo parecido para un proyecto mio pero en ionic, no en react.

Comment: PD: como he dicho antes nosotros damos soluciones apartir de algo que ya tengas, nosotros no recomendamos tecnologias ni damos lecciones sobre una tecnologia en especifico (existen otras plataformas para ello), doy este contexto para que entiendas un poco mejor sobre como funciona el sitio resumidamente. este sitio resuelve dudas especificas con algo que ya tengas en codigo y que hayas investigado por tu cuenta, no con descripciones ni opiniones.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer eso hay que instalar 2 dependencias desde el terminal:

```
expo install expo-localization   

npm install i18n --save
```

Luego en el archivo JS el código sería así:

```
import React from "react"; 
import{ View, Text,} 
from 'react-native';
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';
import i18n from 'i18n-js';


  i18n.translations={
      es:{hola:'Hola',
         amigo:'Amigo'},  

      en:{ hola:'Hello', 
        amigo:'Friend',}  
};  

i18n.locale=Localization.locale;
i18n.fallbacks=true;   

const Home =()=>{ 
  return( 
         <View style={{flex:1, 
         justifyContent: 'center', 
         alignItems: 'center', 
          }} >  
        <Text> 
            {i18n.t('hola')} 
        </Text>    

       <Text>  
          {i18n.t('amigo')} 
       </Text>

       </View> 
)
}   
    export default Home
```

dejo el link de la documentación oficial
[expo localization](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/localization/)
Si tu app tiene mas de un componente que necesites traducir, solo hay que ir agregándolos en el archivo app.js. En el nuevo componente debes insertar esta parte de código para que traduzca de manera automática según la región del usuario (se coloca antes de una función, clase o constante).

```
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization'; 
import i18n from 'i18n-js'; 
i18n.locale=Localization.locale;
i18n.fallbacks=true;
```

Espero que te ayude Saludos Cordiales